# httpd in redhat behaving weird

Tags: apache, redhat, httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxxx.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxxx
    ServerName xxxx.xxx.com
    ServerAlias xxxx www.xxxx.xxx.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
    <Directory /var/www/html/xxxx/cgi>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to host two different websites in a single server(RHEL). I did all required configuration for named based virtual host in httpd.conf......as evident from above conf snapshot. It seems as if I am missing something in the configuration and not able to figure it out.

When I try and access the page....I could see the page but it gets reloaded indefinitely.

Error in ssl_error_log shows Options ExecCGI is off in this directory
Error in error_access_log shows  "POST /cgi/authenticate.py HTTP/1.1" 403 221
Error in ssl_request_log show  TLSv1 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA "POST /cgi/authenticate.py HTTP/1.1" 221

Trying to access 2nd website I am redirected to first.
I am accessing 2nd using IP address xx.xx.xx.xx/path-to-folder/index.html

Please, anybody can thing of solution and what is going wrong??
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

You need to create host configuration file for each site in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

or this previous thread might answer your question.

[Apache 2 Sites-Available Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939686/apache-2-sites-available-configuration)