# Configuration apache2

Tags: apache

I know the topic was answered lot of time but I only find solution for old apache configuration and I really struggle.

Especialy those one :

[how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server)

[apache-2-sites-available-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939686/apache-2-sites-available-configuration)

[error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

(in french)
[apache-resoudre-l-erreur-forbidden-you-don-t-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/](https://www.journaldunet.fr/web-tech/developpement/1202979-apache-resoudre-l-erreur-forbidden-you-don-t-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/)

I already try to apply what I found but it still not work and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here my etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All Order deny,allow Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/usr/www/html/>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here my last logs. I dont know if they are very revelant since i try many configuration.

access.log

```
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:03 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 509 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:03 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 519 "http://192.168.10.69/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:04 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:04 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 519 "http://192.168.10.69/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:24 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 509 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:25 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 519 "http://192.168.10.69/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:31:26 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 519 "http://192.168.10.69/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
192.168.10.49 - - [08/Apr/2019:10:32:17 +0200] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
```

error.log

```
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:03.813961 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2523] [client 192.168.10.49:58744] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://192.168.10.69/
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:04.652973 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2523] [client 192.168.10.49:58744] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:04.793178 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2523] [client 192.168.10.49:58744] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://192.168.10.69/
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:24.955246 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2531] [client 192.168.10.49:58750] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:25.197949 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2531] [client 192.168.10.49:58750] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://192.168.10.69/
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:25.985987 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2531] [client 192.168.10.49:58750] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/
[Mon Apr 08 10:31:26.098043 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 2531] [client 192.168.10.49:58750] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pi/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://192.168.10.69/
```

That the fist time I try configure an apache server... and I'm pretty sure I make a major mistake. I just want to change the location of the server root to access the php files by FTP. Please be patient.

Comment: This is the default config file. You have to check /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory for other vhost files.

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled just constain a link to etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: Great. Are you getting any error messages? Please check your apache logs and post them with the question.

Comment: @srimaln91 I add them

Comment: `/home/usr/www/html/` should be corrected as `/home/pi/www/html` in your config

Comment: I did it. The server crash and dont want to restart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191435/discussion-between-srimaln91-and-julien-maret).